# What conditions should i check while iterating though a cursor to avoid insertion error the last row of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, logic

I have written a code to add columns to a table named **dbo.Master_Table**. 
This table contains all the columns present in the current database.I 
have used two cursors , first cursor ( **TABLE_NAME**) gets me a list of all 
tables in the database and the second cursor ( **COLUMNS_TO_ADD** ) is 
declared within ( TABLE_NAME) which gets me the list of all the columns 
in the database.

**Error** :

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name '**Resolution**' 
>            in table 'dbo.Master_table' is specified more than once.
>
> Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
>            Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 
>           **'Sample_Size'** in table 'dbo.Master_table' is specified more than 
>            once

Both the columns **'Resolution'** and **'Sample_Size'** are the columns of last 
**ORDINAL_POSITION** in their respective tables.It looks like on the last 
iteration the cursor is not able to break the loop and trying to insert 
their columns again. Any help will be appreciated.

```
/* Declaring the variables */

CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.SP_INSERT_MASTER

@TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(max)=NULL,
@COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(20)=NULL,
@DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(20)=NULL,
@LENGTH INT=NULL,
@NUMERIC_PRECISION INT=NULL,
@NUMERIC_SCALE INT=NULL,
@ORDINAL_POSITION INT=NULL,
@Column varchar(max)=NULL,
@SQL varchar(max)=NULL

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

/* Declaring a cursor to fetch the number of tables in the DB */

DECLARE TABLE_NAME_1 CURSOR FOR

select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME NOT 

IN('Master','Sysssislog','XML_DB')


OPEN TABLE_NAME_1

FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_NAME_1
INTO @TABLE_NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0  

--1
BEGIN


  /* Declaring a cursor to get all the columns with their 
     length,precision,scale,ordinal position */

DECLARE COLUMN_TO_ADD CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,NUMERIC_PRECISION,
NUMERIC_SCALE,ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_NAME LIKE '%' + @TABLE_NAME + '%'

OPEN COLUMN_TO_ADD

/* Creating Temporary  table to check redundant records */
----------------------------------------------------------------------


IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE name LIKE'%#Temp2%'
           )

 --2
  BEGIN

 DROP TABLE #TEMP2
 --2
 END;


 select MAX(I.ORDINAL_POSITION) AS ORDINAL,I.TABLE_NAME INTO #TEMP2  from 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I 
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I2
 ON I.TABLE_NAME=I2.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE I.TABLE_NAME NOT IN( 'Master','Sysssislog','XML_DB') group by 
 I.TABLE_NAME


 -----------------------------------------------------------------------


 FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_TO_ADD
 INTO @COLUMN_NAME,@DATA_TYPE,@LENGTH,@NUMERIC_PRECISION,@NUMERIC_SCALE,
 @ORDINAL_POSITION


 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

 --3
 BEGIN


  IF @DATA_TYPE IN ('int','tinyint','bigint')
  SET @Column = (@COLUMN_NAME +' '+ @DATA_TYPE + ' '+   ''  )
  IF @DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','nvarchar')
  SET @Column = (@COLUMN_NAME +' '+ @DATA_TYPE + ' '+ '('+  
  CAST(CASE(isnull(@LENGTH,'')) WHEN -1 THEN 1000 ELSE (isnull(@LENGTH,'')) 
  END AS varchar(max)) +')'+ ''  )
  IF @DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal','numeric')
  SET  @Column = (@COLUMN_NAME +' '+ @DATA_TYPE + ' '+  '('+ 
  cast(@NUMERIC_PRECISION as varchar(max))+','+cast(@NUMERIC_SCALE as 
  varchar(max))+')' + ''  )


   /*
   ADD New Columns TO Master Table
   */


    IF NOT EXISTS
    ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Master_table%'  
    and COLUMN_NAME=@COLUMN_NAME
    )

   --4
   BEGIN

   Set @SQL='ALTER TABLE dbo.Master_table ADD'+ ' ' + (@Column)
   EXEC(@SQL)

   --PRINT @TABLE_NAME

   --PRINT 'Y'
   --PRINT @Column

   FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_TO_ADD
   INTO @COLUMN_NAME,@DATA_TYPE,@LENGTH,@NUMERIC_PRECISION,
   @NUMERIC_SCALE,@ORDINAL_POSITION

   --4
   END;

   ELSE

   IF EXISTS
    (
   select 1 from #TEMP2
   WHERE  @TABLE_NAME=TABLE_NAME and ORDINAL=@ORDINAL_POSITION
    )
   --5
   BEGIN

   PRINT @TABLE_NAME


   FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_NAME_1
   INTO @TABLE_NAME

   --PRINT @TABLE_NAME
   --PRINT 'N'
   --PRINT @Column

   --5
   END;




  FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_TO_ADD
  INTO @COLUMN_NAME,@DATA_TYPE,@LENGTH,@NUMERIC_PRECISION,
  @NUMERIC_SCALE,@ORDINAL_POSITION

  --3
  END;

  FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_NAME_1
  INTO @TABLE_NAME



  --drop #temp1

  CLOSE COLUMN_TO_ADD;
  DEALLOCATE COLUMN_TO_ADD;


  --1
  END;
  CLOSE TABLE_NAME_1;
  DEALLOCATE TABLE_NAME_1;
```

Comment: Why don't you collect the unique column names in one query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, grouping by column name?

Comment: What is the data type of Resolution and of Sample_Size? as reported by the query.  And what are the columns right after those two? and what are their data types?  If column [Resolution+1] has a data type that is not being handled, then @Column will not be set, and and will [Resolution] will be added a second time.

Comment: @GertArnold Great suggestion, but i was trying out some different code style to practice my T-SQL skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks on your code:

- Instead of INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, you can use *catalog views* which provide an `object_id` that can be used for joining the views. Anyway, you don't need 2 cursors.
- Filling table `#TEMP2`, you join each column with each column of the table. You only access one side of the join, so this isn't necessary. Also, the script should create that table only once (you do that inside the outer WHILE loop).
- Your usage of the cursors is inconsistent. If the condition in the IF block in the middle is true, the `COLUMN_TO_ADD` cursor is fetched twice (the second time after the IF statement) without checking the `@@FETCH_STATUS`, and if the condition of the IF statement in the ELSE part is true, the TABLE_NAME_1 cursor moves to the next record without re-denfing the inner cursor which still refers to the columns of the previous table.
- Your outer cursor doesn't exclude the `Master_table` itself.
- Your variables are declared as parameters of the stored procedure.
- The name of your stored procedure starts with the prefix "sp_" which should not be used for user-defined stored procedures
- You do not handle all datatypes. For example, what about `char` and `nchar`?

I don't want to re-write all your code, I'll leave that to you, just one hint to handle all (or at least *more*) datatypes:

```
SET @Column = QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + ' ' + @DATA_TYPE + 
CASE
    WHEN  @DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar') THEN 
        '(' +  CASE @LENGTH WHEN -1 THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(@LENGTH AS varchar(max)) END +')'
    WHEN @DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN
        '(' + CAST(@NUMERIC_PRECISION as varchar(max)) + ',' + CAST(@NUMERIC_SCALE as varchar(max))+')'
    ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: Thank you for you valuable inputs. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my query is solved. I just realized that i was missing the complete table name in the where clause of first TABLE_NAME_1 cursor. ( Used 'Master' instead of Master_Table ).I guess this was the reason why the T-sql query was trying to insert data from dbo.Master_Table again to the same table.
Once is made the change my query passed with no errors. Thanks for your help.